# Conjecture linking multiplicative order of $2$ and semi-primes

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, conjectures

Suppose we have a semi-prime $N=pq$, where $p \ne q$, and $p>2$, $q>2$ 
Let $k$ be the multiplicative order of $2$ mod $N$, then either $p^{2} \bmod k \equiv 1$ or $q^{2}  \bmod k \equiv 1$

<s>Is there a simple proof (disproof) of this fact?</s> There are counterexamples (see answer).
An interesting question is - Are there additional conditions that must hold for the conjecture to be true?

This is somewhat related to a question I asked previously, which was simply a special case of this conjecture when $N = 2^{m}-1$, where the multiplicative order in this case is $m$. See [Conjecture involving semi-prime numbers of the form $2^{x}-1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/645415/conjecture-involving-semi-prime-numbers-of-the-form-2x-1)

Comment: As the answer below demonstrates, there are counterexamples. Interestingly, the conjecture does still hold pretty frequently for smallish odd semiprimes. Ordering them by magnitude, it holds for 333 of the first 666 and 1000 of the first 2701.

Answer (score 1):

This conjecture is wrong. With $p=11, q=23\,$ we have $N=253\,$ and $k=\mathrm{ord}_{253}(2) = 110.$

But $11^2 \equiv 11 \pmod {110}\;$ and $23^2 \equiv 89 \pmod {110}.$

There are alot more counter-examples, e.g. $p=11,q=37\;$ or $p=19,q=23\dots$

Comment: A more systematic way to 'guess' counterexamples would be using the identity $$k=\text{ord}_{pq}(2)=\text{lcm}(\text{ord}_p(2),\text{ord}_q(2)).$$ From here one sees that $k\mid p^2-1$ or $k\mid q^2-1$ if and only if $\text{ord}_p(2)\mid q-1$ or $\text{ord}_q(2)\mid p-1$.